# Getting unexpected 404 errors with a dynamic route using Nuxt.js 2

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm getting unexpected 404 errors in a nuxt.js application I'm building. I've looked at the similar questions and those don't seem to solve my problem so here I am.

I have a page which contains a list of accounts and a detail page for any given account. The directory structure for those pages is:

```
pages
   accounts
      index.vue
      _id.vue
   accounts.vue
```

*accounts.vue* just contains

```
<div>
   <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
</div>
```

The *index.vue* page generates a link to (e.g) `/accounts/80840`.  That all works fine. Clicking on that link generates a 404 error. Looking inside *.nuxt/router.js* I can see

```
routes: [{
    path: "/accounts",
    component: _67e5b8d2,
    children: [{
      path: "",
      component: _dfff464c,
      name: "accounts"
    }, {
      path: ":id",
      component: _f458647c,
      name: "accounts-id"
    }]
  }
]
```

That looks right to me. I'm new to Nuxt so... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `accounts` (directory) and `accounts.vue` at the same time? Keep only one. Also, `/accounts/80840` will lead to the dynamic `_id.vue` file.

Comment: @kissu - because https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#nested-routes suggests that's how it needs to be done. And... the problem here is that '/accounts/80840' leads to a 404 error - it *isn't* leading to the the dynamic file.

Comment: @kissu - removing the accounts.vue file works as you suggested but the 404 issue continues

Comment: Using Nuxt2 or 3? The syntax is not the same for dynamic routes' files.

Comment: I'm using Nuxt2